# Preserve Destination Object Id field in Automapping using Attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, automapper

I've a class Customer

```
public class Customer {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
}
```

I've another class CustomerSetting

```
[AutoMap(typeof(Customer), ReverseMap = true)]
public class CustomerSetting {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string DeliveryAddress { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
}
```

In another file `service.cs` where I defined operations and a mapping.

```
public CustomerSetting getMappedData(){
    var customerModel = _service.getCustomer();
    var customerSetting = _service.getCustomerSetting();
    
    _mapper.map<Customer, CustomerSetting>(customerModel, customerSetting); 
}
```

The issue I'm facing is, CustomerSetting.Id is getting overridden by Customer.Id.
How can I prevent it using Attibutes.

So far, I tried to to use `[Ignore]` and `[IgnoreMap]` on top of field but it sets value to default i.e. 0.

Comment: Just for my understanding, why do you even map them to oneanother?

Comment: @SMSTJ this is very simplified version of my problem. I did so for the shake of understanding. In my original problem, Customer inherits 2 more classes and customer settings inherits customerRequest. I'm trying to figure out how can we ignore mapping using attibute? In my case, it is setting the Id = 0 when I [ignore] or [IgnoreMap].

Comment: Try the UseExistingValue Attribute

Comment: Although its not QUITE clear to me if this is the thing that will help you, since its only mentioned off hand in the documentation
https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Attribute-mapping.html#additional-configuration-options

But is mentioned nowhere else, nor do any examples exist online

Comment: It doesn't work. I'd be best if jimmy can answer why they put UseExistingValue there.

Comment: I took another look, and there seems to be something called UseDestinationValue.
This one is actually documented and has examples
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7084346/automapper-and-usedestinationvalue

https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/11.0-Upgrade-Guide.html

Comment: why don't you use the automapper profile ? it's way more clear and easy to be configured. 
ex: .ForMember(dest=>dest.x,sourse=>sourse.MapFrom(s=>s.y))
 .ForMember(dest=>dest.x , opt => opt.Ignore());

Answer (score 1):

You could try this simple test using console App.

```
    public class Customer
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    [AutoMap(typeof(Customer), ReverseMap = true)]
    public class CustomerSetting
    {
        [Ignore]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int UserId { get; set; }
    }
```

program.cs

```
var configuration = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => cfg.AddMaps("ConsoleApp47"));  //Assembly Name same as project name
var mapper = new Mapper(configuration);

var customerModel = new Customer { Id = 1, Name = "tom" };
var customerSetting = new CustomerSetting { Id = 3, UserId = 13 };

mapper.Map<Customer, CustomerSetting>(customerModel, customerSetting);

Console.WriteLine(JsonSerializer.Serialize(customerSetting));
```

Test result
[image]

Comment: There is no need to explicitly specify generic arguments.